# Can not open .exe with shellExecute function in C++

Tags: c++, windows, codeblocks, sfml, shellexecute

i want to open a .exe (lets call it A)  when i execute another c++ program (lets call it B), so i have A and B in execution at the same time.

For this, i use this function in B code:

```
HINSTANCE result;

result=ShellExecute(NULL,NULL,"d:\\Users\\bci\\Desktop\\Animation\\bin\\Release\\Animation2.exe",NULL ,NULL,SW_SHOWDEFAULT);

cout << "Result is " <<(int)result <<endl;
```

Result value is 42, and A does not manage to open.
The error i get is this:

```
Failed to open file "player.png": Unable to open file
Failed to load player spritesheet!
```

This corresponds to this part of A´s code:

```
// load texture (spritesheet)
    sf::Texture texture;
    if (!texture.loadFromFile("player.png"))
    {
        std::cout << "Failed to load player spritesheet!" << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }
```

A and B were both built using code::blocks as IDE with the GCC/G++ compiler and GDB debugger from TDM-GCC (version 4.9.2, 32 bit, SJLJ).

I am doing this in windows 7 64 bits (enterprise and professional, both same error).

Also, i do not know if it is worth telling, but i am using SFML library in A, as you can see in

```
 sf::Texture texture;
```

I think this is related somehow to permissions for opening a file from a program you are calling, but i am not sure how to solve this.

Actually A and B work perfectly on their own, but B is unable to open A by this meanings.

I am pretty sure i have made that image as unrestricted as i can with the right click->properties->security options, but it does not seem enough.

Can someone help me with this?

Comment: I expect `player.png` is not in the current directory.

Comment: In regards to A and B, what do you mean by "in execution at the same time"? Also, beware that the current working directory passed to the process with ShellExec will be different than your parent program's (to verify this just write a file to path at program arg[0] and see where it ends up) so loading a relative path could be the culprit. Regardless, whatever you are trying to do here may be better accomplished using a static library instead of an executable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ShellExecute` has an `lpDirectory` parameter that sets the shell's current working directory to whatever you want for the duration of the call.

You've set it to `NULL`, so the current working directory is unchanged (could be the location of `B`'s executable, or whatever else you made it). Program `A` is using relative paths and therefore expects `player.png` to be in the current working directory; presumably the distribution makes it so that the file is *actually* found at the location of `A`'s executable, and just assumes the two are the same. In this scenario, they're not.

Only you can know what the current working directory is *supposed* to be for `A`, but based on the above assumption, you should set `lpDirectory` to `"d:\\Users\\bci\\Desktop\\Animation\\bin\\Release\\"`.

Answer (score 0):

Program A is being executed correctly. The problem is that when you shell execute it from program B, it runs with the current working directory of program B. Hence it cannot find `player.png`. You either need to edit program A to provide the full path to `player.png`, or you need to copy `player.png` into the same folder as program B.

Comment: It would be better to make the `ShellExecute` occur with the proper working directory, no? Instead of hacking around with file copies and hardcoded paths. Hint: there's an `lpDirectory` parameter...

Comment: Good point, I agree - assuming the question-asker really does want that working directory for A (which I suspect would be the case).

Comment: @SamHolloway: If they want some other directory, they still have to set that :)